# Delay in loading home page modules

Tags: joomla-3.x, seo, performance, wpo

In some sites in their home pages, as u scroll down, modules appear one by one.
I think this enhances page load time. How can i do this in Joomla? Is it doable? Is there a plugin or something for this matter?

Comment: I think what you're seeing doesn't actually "load" the module when in the viewport. It's already loaded but is hidden, then when it's in the viewport, it becomes visible.

Comment: What you're thinking of may increase server loading time, but will absolutely destroy your server resources as it will require a load of Ajax requests.

Answer (score 3):

"Lazy loading" may be what you are describing.

There is a free Joomla extension, "[Lazy Load for Joomla!](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/lazy-load-for-joomla)" which helps with this but is more for images than modules.

Comment: yeah, exactly. jch plugin has this function for images. and i thought it would be good to do the same thing about modules.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very careful using the lazyload method. I have seen many instances where the content (images) at top do not load until the page scrolls even 1 pixel.

You might consider using scrollfire/magic.. this allows you to load certain content based on where the user is on their scrolling position.

http://materializecss.com/scrollfire.html
http://scrollmagic.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can use sp-pagebuilder. The functionality is there by default. In sp-pagebuilder, goto row settings chose the animation what you want, increase the delay time. U are done.